# Execute Excel file containing a particular string

Tags: ssis

I need a solution for dynamic excel connection manager which would only pick filename containing a particular string. 
For that, 
1. I could set a variable @filename
2. Set the expression for a Excel connection manager 'connectionstring' property to @filename.

I just need an expression here so that if the @filename contains a string 'test' within (e.g. a124test.xlsx, test123.xlsx, xyztest478844.xlsx) then only the file would be processed or else not.

Thanks in advance.
Asit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an int variable say "val".
Use an expression task and write the below expression

@[user::val]=FindString(@[user::FileName],"test",1)

In the above expression, if the FileName variable contains test, the val would be set to 1 else it would be set to 0.

In the precedence constraint of the expression task and the next task, right click on the precedence constraint, set the evaluation operation as "Expression and Constraint". Choose Value as "success" and in the expression
write @[user::val]==1.Click Ok.

So, this precedence constraint would execute the next task only if the value of the variable is 1 else it won't go ahead.

Comment: Thanks Kapil, the expression helped

Answer (score 0):

use a foreach loop and define folder and then define files as *test*.xlsx and variable map the filepathName fully qualified to a variable.

create an expression on your excel connection to use this variable as ExcelFilePath.

Comment: test has asterisks around it.